# set up arquillian.xml and glassfish-resource.xml

Tags: java, jdbc, glassfish, jboss-arquillian, payara

i was following [this tutorial](http://arquillian.org/guides/testing_java_persistence/) but i have some problem to set jdbc connection.

in my arquillian.xml i wrote:

```
...
<container qualifier="payara-remote" default="true">
    <configuration>
        <property name="resourcesXml">
            src/test/resources-payara-remote/glassfish-resources.xml
        </property>
    </configuration>
</container>
...
```

when i run my test i get this warning:

```
AVVERTENZA: Configuration contain properties not supported by the backing object org.jboss.arquillian.container.glassfish.remote_3_1.GlassFishRestConfiguration
Unused property entries: {resourcesXml=
            src/test/resources-payara-remote/glassfish-resources.xml
        }
Supported property names: [adminHttps, remoteServerHttpPort, libraries, type, remoteServerAddress, target, remoteServerAdminPort, remoteServerAdminHttps, adminUser, authorisation, adminPort, properties, adminHost, adminPassword]
```

so i think "resourceXml" isn't supported... how i can tell arquillian to use that file?

moreover, in that file i declare a jdbc/test. What i have to write in persistence.xml to use that db connection?

thank you in advance

**UPDATE**

*I wish to use my test-db declaring jdbc connection in the "src/test/resources-payara-remote/glassfish-resources.xml" (without create a jdbc connection in the **remote server**), but i don't know how to set arquillian to use jdbc connection declared in the .xml file.*

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/arquillian/reference/snapshot/en-US/html/containers.html#d0e713; Table 4.1. Target containers supported by Arquillian seems to list the supported containers and "payara-remote" does not seem to be listed

Comment: hummm... but it talks about supported property name... so the supported servers support resourceXml property name?

Comment: It seems that you want to pass resources configuration file to a remote server, which does not make sense. You probably want to use embedded server. See my answer for details.

Comment: @hammerfest You are wrong. The list what you mentioned only describes the supported containers. The "qualifier" in arquillian.xml is just an alias name (simple string). It is used when you have more then one container configuration. You can activate the proper configuration via pom.xml: build > plugin > maven-surefire-plugin > configuration > systemPropertyVariables > arquillian.launch > payara-remote

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to create a JDBC resource on a remote GlasFish/Payara server, the best way to do it is to package `glassfish-resources.xml` into your deployment inside your test (in `@Deployment` method, use `.addAsWebInfResource("glassfish-resources.xml")`. When the server finds this file `glassfish-resources.xml` in `WEB-INF` folder of the application, it will create the resources temporarily, until the arquillian test suite undeploys the application.

The GlassFish/Payara remote arquillian connector doesn't provide setting up resources from an xml. This feature is only provided by the `glassfish-embedded` connector, which runs GlassFish/Payara inside your test JVM. The embedded connector is what is used in the tutorial you said you followed. Actualy, if you want to run your tests against a remote GlassFish/Payara server, you should compare the steps to test against remote WildFly in the tutorial. It also includes adding a XML with resources into the deployment: `.addAsWebInfResource("jbossas-ds.xml")`

If you want to use GlassFish embedded connector with Payara, just add the following dependencies in maven pom.xml:

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-glassfish-embedded-3.1</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>fish.payara.extras</groupId>
                <artifactId>payara-embedded-all</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.1.163.0.1</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
```

Comment: Where should i put glassfish-resources.xml file for testing?  /src/test/web-inf?

Comment: Into `src/test/resources/`. It will be picked up from there by `.addAsWebInfResource("glassfish-resources.xml")`.